# Red ovals around the circles of a ul type="circle"

Tags: html, css

Until today I didn't have this problem, but now I do.  I have an unordered list with circles.  The circles are colored the same as the text, BUT I now have small red ovals around each of the circles.  Why?

Here is the html code:

```
<div class="h1_info"><b>Headline</b></div><br>

<div class="zebra_01">Intro text.</div>

<ul type="circle">
<li class="MC_01B">List item 1</li>
<li class="MC_01B">List item 2</li></ul>
```

Here is the css code:

```
.MC_01B{
    color: rgb(175,222,162);
    font-family: CamphorW01-Thin, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13pt;
    width: auto;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Until today this list did not have red ovals around the circles, but now they do.  I haven't changed the class or anything else on the page.  Research doesn't turn up anything about red ovals.  What gives?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: This code is fine and should not effect the bullets. Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w3cpd7hx/  Something other than the code provided is effecting it. or its just in your computer, can't reproduce.

Comment: it's probably the font-family

Comment: i can't see any red ovals. This is probably because of your browser. Even extensions can cause this.

Comment: Thanks, everyone.  I'll keep working on it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer to this bizarre situation.  Lurking in my (now voluminous) css code was this, which I don't need any longer:

```
li::before {content: counter(li); color: red;
  display: inline-block; width: 1em;
  margin-left: -1em}
```

And that caused the red ovals.

Thanks again to all three of you.